# How to change select options based on other selection ( Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an 4 Select component with the same list options. If I choose an option, that one will be remove from the list of other Select components so that no 2 Select have identical result. Here is the code:

```
listStaff = [
  {id: 1, name: 'John Doe'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Walter White},
  {id: 3, name: 'Jesse Pinkman}
  {id: 4, name: 'Saul Goodman}
  {id: 5, name: 'Gus Fring}
  {id: 6, name: 'Skyler White}
]
```

```
const [staff, setStaff] = useState([])
      <Select
        allowClear
        placeholder="Choose staff #1"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeStaff(e, 0)}
        value={staff[0]}
      >
        {listStaff?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Select.Option key={item?.id} value={item?.id}>
              {item?.name}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        })}
      </Select>

      <Select
        allowClear
        placeholder="Choose staff #2"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeStaff(e, 1)}
        value={staff[1]}
      >
        {listStaff?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Select.Option key={item?.id} value={item?.id}>
              {item?.name}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        })}
      </Select>

      <Select
        allowClear
        placeholder="Choose staff #3"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeStaff(e, 2)}
        value={staff[2]}
      >
        {listStaff?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Select.Option key={item?.id} value={item?.id}>
              {item?.name}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        })}
      </Select>

      <Select
        allowClear
        placeholder="Choose staff #4"
        onChange={(e) => onChangeStaff(e, 3)}
        value={staff[3]}
      >
        {listStaff?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Select.Option key={item?.id} value={item?.id}>
              {item?.name}
            </Select.Option>
          );
        })}
      </Select>
```

Here is what I try:

```
const onChangeStaff = (id, index) => {
      let arrTemp = [...listStaff]
      const i = arrTemp.findIndex(r => r.id == id)
      if(i > -1 ){
         arrTemp.splice(i, 1)
      } else {
         return arrTemp
      }
      setListStaff(arrTemp)
   };
```

I can remove the chosen option from the list but when a clear the Select or choose another option, the previous one do not revert but lost permanently. So how can I remove one option when choosing but revert that one back when deselect? Thank you.
Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-dew-h6qxc4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i messing around with your code a bit. try this

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Select } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [listStaff, setListStaff] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Walter White" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jesse Pinkman" },
    { id: 3, name: "Gus Fring" },
    { id: 4, name: "Saul Goodman" },
    { id: 5, name: "John Doe" },
    { id: 6, name: "Skyler White" }
  ]);

  const [selectedStaff, setSelectedStaff] = useState(new Array(4).fill(null));

  const handleChangeStaff = (id, i) => {
    setSelectedStaff(p => {
      const newSelectedStaff = [...p];
      newSelectedStaff[i] = id === undefined ? null : listStaff.find(ls => ls.id === id);
      return newSelectedStaff;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {new Array(4).fill("").map((_, i) => ( 
        <Select
        allowClear
        placeholder={`Choose staff #${i+1}`}
        onChange={(id) => handleChangeStaff(id, i)}
        key={i}
      >
        {listStaff.filter(ls => selectedStaff.find(ss => ss !== null && ss.id === ls.id) === undefined).map(ls => (
            <Select.Option key={ls.id} value={ls.id}>
              {ls.name}
            </Select.Option>
         ))}
      </Select>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried and your solution work. However, I still don't understand the part "listStaff.filter((ls) => selectedStaff.find((ss) => ss !== null && ss?.id === ls?.id) === undefined)" mean? I understand if there no "=== undefined" part, we will get an array of selected options. But with that part, we will get the listStaff without the chosen one. Could you explain ?

Comment: `listStaff.filter(ls => selectedStaff.find(ss => ss !== null && ss.id === ls.id) === undefined)` means take out staff(s) from `listStaff` if those staff(s) is/are already exist in `seletedStaff`.